# iPhone: TableView inside UIScrollview, show vaccillating scrollbars around

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I have added some table and other vies in a scrollview. scrolling in tables are working fine. But in the parent scrollview, when scrolling, a vacillating vertical scrollbars are shown, sometimes it even come to the middle  of the screen. sometime show at the left side of the screen. and not limited to the  vertical scrollbar region. When I set the `showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO`, it is not shown. But do you know why the scrollbar is moving around.

DashboardView is a subclass of `UIScrollView`.

```
dashboard=[[DashboardView alloc] initWithFrame:fullScreenRect];
dashboard.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,700); // must do!
dashboard.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
dashboard.bounces = YES;
self.view = dashboard;


@implementation DashboardView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
}

- (void) layoutSubviews{

    NSArray *views = self.subviews; 

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"CollapseExpand" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];

    UIView *view = [views objectAtIndex: 0];
    CGRect rect = view.frame;

    for (int i = 1;  i < [views count]; i++ ) {     
        view = [views objectAtIndex:i];
        view.frame = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height);
        rect = view.frame;
    }

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that scrollbars is subviews of scroll too. Exclude it from `views` array, before doing something with views.

Answer (score 0):

Yap. that solved my problem. It seems Scrollbars are a kind of UIImageView. If anybody need it, this is my new code which works fine.

```
(void) layoutSubviews{

NSArray *views = self.subviews; 

[UIView beginAnimations:@"CollapseExpand" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];

//CGRect fullScreenRect=[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];       
//  [self.view insertSubview:balanceView belowSubview:profileView];


UIView *view = [views objectAtIndex: 0];
CGRect rect = view.frame;

for (int i = 1;  i < [views count]; i++ ) {     
    view = [views objectAtIndex:i];
    if ([view isMemberOfClass: [UIView class] ]) {
        //CFShow(view);
        view.frame = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height);
        rect = view.frame;          
    }

}

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

}